# The markers in my plot are far away from where they should be in the image

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code, which plots a normal plt.plot with markers in each value, however the markers text is far away from the marker point as seen in the image. Is there something I can do? Does it depends in the figure size? because I also tried with different figure sizes.

[image: Plot image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(10)
f.set_figheight(8)


x = df["State"]
y = df["Total revenue"]


def add_value_label(x_list,y_list):
    for i in range(1, len(x_list)+1):
        plt.text(i,y_list[i-1],y_list[i-1])

add_value_label(x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, marker='o',color ='orange',markerfacecolor='orange',markeredgecolor='orange')



plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're counting your X values from 1 and your Y values from 0.  You can see that in the plot -- the values are right, but they're shifted one x column to the right.

```
def add_value_label(x_list,y_list):
    for i,xv in enumerate(x_list):
        plt.text(xv,y_list[i],y_list[i])
```